# Under what conditions is an infinite orthonormal set a basis of $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, schauder-basis

I have an infinite orthonormal set in $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ and want to know under which conditions it is as basis of $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ and how to prove that.

In the finite dimensional case, the cardinality of the set would just have to be equal to the dimension of the space, but I suppose in the infinite dimensional case (such as $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$) this doesn't hold.

I know the usual conditions for being a basis such as its span being dense in the space or it being a Schauder basis or a total orthonormal set, but do not know how to work with that in the case below:

I take a given orthonormal basis $\lbrace \phi_i \rbrace_{i=1}^{\infty}  $ of $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$, say the weighted Hermite Polynomials, and modify it as follows:
$ \psi_i(x) = \phi_i( g(x)) * \vert g^\prime (x) \vert^\frac{1}{2} $

This conserves orthonormality, but I do not now whether or under which circumstances this is still a basis.
What conditions do I need on g? Maybe just bijectivity?

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: One often useful way of proving that  it is a basis is to take a function orhthogonal each one of these and show that it must be $0$.